# In DBSCAN, what does eps represent actually?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

Suppose that I have already found the *eps* for all density. I applied the methodology from here http://ijiset.com/v1s4/IJISET_V1_I4_48.pdf

If you don't mind, please open page 5 and see at Proposed Algorithm section. At step 10.1, the paper tells us to calculate the number of objects in *eps-neighborhood*.

What does *eps* represent actually? It is a radius to draw a circle right? So, why the radius is so small, smaller than distances between two objects? If so, the MinPts will be 0 forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if used with Euclidean distance, then it is a radius.

It is not infinitely small (it does *not tend to 0*). It's just supposed to be small compared to the data set extends, but the authors could have named it "r" instead.

Use the *original paper* to understand the algorithm, not some indian journal variant of it.

Comment: then, what paper do you suggest? I've been searching until now, more than 5 papers I guess, but still get the same question

Comment: Reference 1 in the paper you linked. Ester, Kriegel, Sander, Xu, KDD 1996

Comment: I understand now, but little problem here. Why do Weka take very small _eps_ value? Original paper suggest to use k-dist(p) value which is 'big' since the distance between points is bigger than _eps_. So what should I do?

Comment: Weka is good for classification, but don't use it for clustering. But I have to disagree: the *default* value of 0.9 is not "very small", in particular since it uses distances after scaling every attribute to [0:1]. For one-dimensional data, 0.9 would be roughly 90% of your data set, much too large. But there clearly shouldn't be a default value for this parameter at all.

Comment: I primarily use ELKI for clustering, because it's fast; and for many algorithms there is no other tool at all that has a working implementation. Too bad it lacks classification, but fortunately I don't need classification often. I'd love to see ELKI with classification.

Answer (score 0):

In Euclidean distance, it is the radius. Selection of Eps is a little difficult.

This problem is related to model selection, i.e., the selection of a particular model and its corresponding parametrization. In the case of k-means (which requires from the user the number of clusters as input) there is a plethora of measures in the literature that can help in the selection of the best number of clusters, for instance: silhouette, c-index, dunn, davies-bouldin. These measures are the so-called relative validity criteria.

In the case of Density-based clustering algorithms, there are some measures too, for instance: CDbw and DBCV.